# Need guidance to install Miraclecast using Cmake

Tags: wireless, wifi-direct

I'm new to Ubuntu and went through the readme file on MiracleCast zip download. I'm using CMake, but can't seem to figure out what to do once i download the zip folder. How i use CMake to download and run MiracleCast?

Comment: Can you provide a like to some sort of documentation ? Normally you would extract the archive and generally there is a README, but who knows.

Comment: here's the link to the documentation, this has all the requisite details
https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Extract the .zip `unzip your_archive.zip` , cd into the resulting directory, and follow https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast/wiki/Building

Comment: being new to these terms, could you kindly elaborate where exactly do i "unzip your_archive.zip" do i do this in the terminal or in Cmake? 
to build miraclecast, do i input the commands into Cmake or the terminal?
thank you for your kind patience

Comment: Enter the commands I gave you in a terminal. cmake is also a command you enter in the terminal. If you are new to the command line, take a look at this site - http://linuxcommand.org/ , sepecially the first section http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_learning_the_shell.php

Comment: the following errors occured
Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:467 (message):
  pkg-config tool not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:588 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  CMakeLists.txt:26 (pkg_check_modules)


CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:467 (message):

Comment: You will need to contact MiracleCast for support on that error as it is a 3rd party application and it does not look like a problem you can fix and it is unlikely people here are going to read and modify the source code for you.

Comment: Compiling software from source code is an advanced topic. Not for beginners. Basic skills like how-to-unzip-an-archive and how-to-use-the-terminal are assumed. You are trying to race a bicycle without learning how to ride first.

Comment: i'm sorry for any inconvenience caused. but i guess that's the fastest way to learn. maybe i'll try to figure out how to operate a space-ship.. that might make learning a bicycle relatively easier ;D

Answer (score 2):

I built the package successfully on my 17.10 system.

First, let's address the error above. Do you have `pkg-config` installed? Check:

```
which pkg-config
```

If it is not found, install it:

```
sudo apt-get install pkg-config
```

On my system, I needed to install some dependencies; my list is here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25925482/ The exact versions you need may vary if you are not running 17.10 64-bit, fully updated.

Next, I followed the build directions; from the terminal:

```
git clone https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast.git
cd miraclecast
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
```

If all goes well, the response should be:

```
-- Checking for module 'libsystemd'
--   Found libsystemd, version 234
-- Checking for module 'systemd>=213'
--   Found systemd, version 234
-- Compiling with Readline support
-- Compiling with Readline support
-- Checking for module 'check'
--   Found check, version 0.10.0
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/chili/Desktop/Forum/miraclecast/build
```

Next, do:

```
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: thank a ton for the dependency list, is there a quick way to download the softwares mentioned on the list?

Comment: Sadly, none that I know of. Some are dependencies of the others and, as you install one, several more will also be installed as dependencies. Keep track and it will go along pretty quickly.